Samsung Odyssey display only detected as Non-PnP
I have a Samsung Odyssey G52A display, and using a HDMI to usb-c cable.
The issue is that when plugging in the monitor it gets recognized as non-pnp, and they flicker like im plugging it in and out every 20 seconds.
I have tried to reset NVRAM, reset Display Configuration and restarted with or without cable to display.
It works some times when im just plugging it in and out, after about 20-60 times it suddenly just identifies it as odyssey with correct hz and resolution.
The monitor works with other computers.
Specs:
USB-C to HDMI 2.1 8K30Hz 4K120Hz 48Gbps HDR compatible with Thunderbolt 3 och 4.
"Support for DisplayPort Alt Mode 1.4, please note that the USB-C port on your device must support DisplayPort Alt Mode 1.4 for the adapter to work properly."
I checked my thunderbolt ports and they had Speed: Up to 40Gb/s x1.
Any suggestions?
UPDATE: SOLUTION
Apperently it was an issue with the Alt Mode 1.4 for the usb-c to HDMI cable.
I switched to a new cable Display Port to USB-C and it works perfectly. This one: https://www.amazon.se/Belkin-DisplayPort-1-4-kabel-Alt-l%C3%A4ge-bak%C3%A5tkompatibel/dp/B0BJTRC3MC?th=1

Welcome to Ask Different. What is the model / year of your Mac?  If possible, could you try a different cable and report back?

@jaume Hello, and thank you :). I have MacBookPro16,1 model identifier. I bought a new cable - same specs but usb-c to display port and now it works perfectly.

I'm glad it works now. It'd be great if could add an answer explaining that a USB-C-to-DP cable did the trick. You can then mark it as accepted and collect the reward while helping others with a similar issue. Thank you in advance.
